# Error concatenating a string

Tags: java

Why am I getting errors and an unexpected return value?

```
public class Person {
 String name;

public Person(String personName) {
        name = personName;
}

public String greet(String yourName) {
        return String.format("Hi " + %s + ", my name is" + %s, name, yourName);
 }
}
```

Comment: you don't do `" + %s + "`  just do `"(Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);`

Answer (score 2):

%s should be embedded in your String, and should not be separated with a plus, for example:

```
return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
```

You could also do:

```
return "Hi " + name + ", my name is " + yourName;
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.format` needs a string (the first parameter) to be the "guide" of the formatted result.

The first parameter is malformed since the %s is outside the string guide.

try this one:

```
return String.format( "Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName );
```